# Delphi, can't create a class due to E2029

Tags: delphi

This is my code:

```pascal
program FirstProject;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

//Implementation

uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TPerson = class
  public
    name: string;
    age: integer;
    constructor Create(newName: string; newAge: integer);
  end;

implementation

constructor TPerson.Create(newName: string; newAge: integer)
begin

end;
```

When I get to `implementation` it shows me this error:

> Declaration expected but impementation found

I suspect it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

There are three problems:

1. `implementation` should be removed. `program`s don't have `interface` and `implementation` sections, only `unit`s do.
2. The semicolon is missing on the first line of the constructor's definition.
3. The body of the program is missing.

Here's the fixed version:

```
program FirstProject;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TPerson = class
  public
    name: string;
    age: integer;
    constructor Create(const newName: string; newAge: integer);
 end;

constructor TPerson.Create(const newName: string; newAge: integer);
begin

end;

begin
  // Write your program here.
end.
```

Comment: (I also added the `const` prefix to the `newName` parameter, because non-`const` `string` parameters hurt my eyes.)